# Temporarily remove joins while using find (cakePHP)

Tags: php, database, cakephp, controller

I'm trying to remove the joins during a single `find()`. All I want is to retrieve the user's subscriptions and not all the tables/fields that they are related to them.

I have tried

```
$subscriptions = $this->User->find('first', 
    array(
        'fields'     => array('User.subscriptions'),
        'join'       => array(''),
        'conditions' => 
            array(
                'User.id'=> $userID
            )
));
```

If kept with the `joins`, it could potentially be a performance issue in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the containable behavior.

In your User model (or the AppModel) add this:

```
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

And then, on your controller:

```
$this->User->contain();
$subscriptions = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'fields' => array('User.subscriptions'),
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.id' => $userID
    ),
));
```

The CakePHP book has more documentation  http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable

Comment: +1 again for using Containable over recursive, much more flexible. When you get to pretty complex joins using Containable in a nested "contain" is a real winner and negates the need to use unbindModel etc.

Answer (score 4):

try to add a recursive value of -1:

```
$subscriptions = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'fields' => array('User.subscriptions'),
    'join' => array(''),
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.id' => $userID
    ),
    'recursive' => -1
));
```

A -1 recursive value will make the query retrieve only the fields from User tables without any joins.